# Running a pthread-program on spike

Tags: riscv

I have built the riscv-linux compiler and riscv-linux and am now running Linux on spike. I compiled the following application:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//thread function
void* thread_func(void* arg) {
  printf("Hello from thread with identifier %lu\n", pthread_self());
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  pthread_t threads[4];
  int i;

  //create 4 threads
  for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &thread_func, NULL);
  }

  //join threads
  for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I included the application, which I compiled like this:

```
riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -o pthreads -lpthread pthreads.c
```

in the disk image. The problem I now have is, that when I try to run this application it very often (nearly every time) does not complete and only gives me a part of the output:

```
# pthreads
Hello from thread with identifier 137457340928
He
```

After this spike completely crashes. The program seems to abort randomly. I ran the program several times and also observed a completion with full output. I made sure SMP support is turned on and started spike with -p 4. My question now is if I somewhere made a mistake or if there is a problem with spike or Linux?